# How to build a table of trigonometric ratios?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, reference-request, advice

In Appendix D of the 6th edition of Stewart's Calculus, we find example 3 which tells us to find the exact trigonometric ratios for $t = 2\pi/3$.  The solution says --- from Figure 10 we see that a point on the terminal line for $t = 2\pi/3$ is $P(-1, \sqrt 3)$.  From this point I can follow the example.  After solving the problem, Stewart shows a table of various values for $\sin t$ and $\cos t$ saying these were computed from the method of Example 3.

What I cannot do alone is come up with Figure 10.

[image: Figure]
<sup>*(Figure 10, Appendix D, Stewart's Calculus, 6th edition)*</sup>

I know how to draw the angles.  I can find the point (-1, 0) and deduce that base of the triangle has length 1.  I know I can stretch the angle-delimiting line and say it has length 2.  Omg, I just solved my difficulty: now with Pythagoras I can get the height $\sqrt 3$ and then I will have the point $P$.  Until now I had not realized how he had reached the coordinates of the point $P$.

Okay, so let me ask another question --- are there any other methods of building these tables?  I need to reduce the amount of information I must memorize.  I need methods that I can recall quickly and compute quickly on the spot --- on a test, say.

I once read the chapter on trigonometry by Alfred North Whitehead's "An Introduction to Mathematics".  I'm going to read it again to see if he teaches us to build such tables.  Any other recommendation?

Comment: I recommend avoiding the use of tables, and instead, stretching your intuition.  You can see that as $\theta$ goes from $0$ through $(2\pi)$, traveling counter-clockwise, it traverses quadrant 1, then quadrant 2, then quadrant 3, and then quadrant 4.  Quadrant 1 has sine and cosine positive, while quadrant 3 is the reverse.  Quadrant 2 has sine positive and cosine negative, while quadrant 4 is the reverse.  Beyond that, familiarity with the special angles of $\pi/6, \pi/4,$ and $\pi/3$ should be sufficient for most of the corresponding Math problems that you will face.   ...see next comment

Comment: Once in a blue moon, you may have to grapple with a trig function against something like $\pi/12$ or $\pi/5$.  However, you should expect that when the book/class goes down that path, you will be given advance training, so that the unusual problem represents nothing more than an application of your training.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice.  Appreciate.  I'm really working on my intuition and I'm all against memorization, but, honestly (and in my very humble opinion), when I'm so lost (as I am on this) it helps me to memorize some values and little by little go on seeing them in places and understanding why they appear there.  Soon enough, I acquire some intuition.  For instance, when I'm so lost at a problem, I memorize the problem so that I can put it to other people orally, away from books, paper and pencil.  So, these tables (to me) represent my work in computing these sines and cosines I know.

Comment: But although I understood Stewart's example $3$ now, I am not able to build more triangles to get the rest of the table.  If you don't mind, I'm going to edit the question and put a new question there --- if that's okay.  (I need time to think on how to phrase it.  Stay tuned! Thanks a lot.)